# Can a dependent clause specify a verb phrase?

Tags: verbs, subordinate-clauses

I am not sure if "specify" is the right word here, so please edit it if there is a more suitable expression.

So I know that noun phrases can be "specified" by dependent clauses, like this,

> The cat *that was lying there* woke up.

In which *that was lying there* is a dependent clause that "specifies" cat. But can you do the same thing with the verb phrase/verb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course.

> The cat *that was lying there* woke up ***with a satisfied yawn***.

---

**Updated**: I am adding to this based on some comments.

In my revised version of the example sentence, the verb is *woke*. It is modified by **with a satisfied yawn** which acts adverbially—it describes *how* the cat woke up. In the same fashion, **that was lying there** acts adjectivally to modify the noun *cat*.

---

There is a slight difference between the two however. **That was lying there** is a *relative* clause, whereas **with a satisfied yawn** is not.

I can think of no way of modifying the example sentence that produces an adverbial relative clause after *woke up*, but I can think of an alternative sentence:

> I didn't know ***who would be there***.

Here, the verb is *know* and **who would be there** is both a relative and adverbial clause that modifies it.

Comment: That is a prepositional phrase. Notice that it does not contain a verb.

Comment: @DarthCadeus The verb is **woke** and **with a satisfied yawn** acts adverbially—it describes **how** the cat woke up. By the same analysis, **that was lying there** acts adjectivally to modify the noun **cat**.

Comment: But the point is not what with a satisfied yawn describes, but what it is. I know verbs can have specifiers, I just do not know if it can be specified by a *clause*

Comment: @DarthCadeus I'm still confused by what you mean by "specified" if not "modified." Are you perhaps looking for an adverbial phrase that is also a *relative* clause? I can't think of how to modify your example sentence off the top of my head, but consider this: "I didn't **know** ***who would be there.***" Is that what you're looking for?